# Xamarin Black screen when changing screens

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an Xamarin App

I get this black screen blimp or sometimes a constant black screen when switching Screens between shells

Is there any solution for this? or what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you navigate from one `Shell` to another `Shell`? `Shell` cannot be nested or navigate, If you want to navigate pages in shell, you can refer to this thread.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation , If not, Can you provide demo  that could re-prodcue this issue?

Comment: Its basic navigation it has 3 shells a two simple pages with lists and a page with list and map. And I am following the documentation

Comment: Can you share a demo in github? Because I cannot reproduce your issue.